# how to retain an object in java servlets as long as server works?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to create an object in java servlet and I need to persist the object into server session not user session I know how to do it in asp.net but in java servlet I am clueless.

Comment: y you want that object, you may elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set it in the application scope.

From a servlet,

```
public void doPost(...) {
   getServletContext().setAttribute("myPersistentObject", someObject);
}
```

From a JSP,

```
<%
    application.setAttribute("myPersistentObject", someObject);
%>
```

Or better still, use JSTL:

```
<c:set value="${someObject}" scope="application" />
```

Answer (score 1):

A servlet is a singleton. You can assign an instance variable of your servlet. Just make sure to properly synchronize the access to this variable.

You may also use the "application" scope, i.e. set an attribute in the `ServletContext`. The same synchronization warning applies:

```
request.getServletContext().setAttribute("foo", foo);
```

This way, the same object will be available from all the servlets, and from the JSPs using

```
${applicationScope.foo}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide more information for more precise answer.
In simple term, set the object as a static member of the servlet.

Answer (score 1):

you can set object to [ServletContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html).

```
getServletContext().setAttribute("myObject1", object1);
```

will solve the purpose,you may elaborate your problem to get better answer.